# Como atualizar um banco de dados (SQLite DB) usando a biblioteca WorkManager?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, sqlite

Estou usando a biblioteca workmanager para mostrar uma notificação ao usuário indicando a hora de tomar seu remédio.

Também estou usando a biblioteca SQLiteDatabase para armazenar as informações do medicamento como: estoque, quantidade administrada, nome do remédio, tipo do remédio (comprimido, gotas), intervalo de horas entre as administrações, etc....

Eu uso o seguinte código para executar as notificações baseado no intervalo de horas que o usuário informar:

```
static final String TASK_ID = "data_update";
int intervalo = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());

PeriodicWorkRequest work =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(DataUpdateWorker.class,
                intervalo, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TASK_ID,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, work);
```

E para mostrar a notificação eu uso:

```
public class MyPeriodicWorker extends Worker {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
SQLiteOpenHelperDatbase SQLOP;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    RemoteViews remoteCollapseViews = new RemoteViews("com.exemplifique.seetview"
            ,R.layout.notification_collapsed);
    RemoteViews remoteExpandeViews = new RemoteViews("com.exemplifique.seetview"
            ,R.layout.notification_expanded);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashScreen_ConfirmeAlarme.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID);


    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_farm_white);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
    builder.setCustomContentView(remoteCollapseViews);
    builder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteExpandeViews);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer     =    MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarme);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
```

Até aqui, meu aplicativo funciona bem. Entretanto meu código está incompleto. Isso porque toda vez uma notificação for informada ao usuário, as informações do do medicamento que estão armazenadas no SQLiteDatabase devem ser atualizadas.

Exemplo:

-Antes da notificação ser mostrada:

TABELA

Nome,Categoria,estoque,administração,intervalo em horas

(Rivotril,Comprimido,10,1,12 em 12 horas)

-Depois da notificação ser mostrada:

(Rivotril,Comprimido,9,1,12 em 12 horas)

Ou seja, quando a notificação for gerada, as informações do banco de dados devem ser atualizadas. Agora como eu faço isso?

Visto que, para fazer as atualizações destas informações é necessário indicar em qual tabala está armazenado as informações.
O seguinte código mostra o que é necessário para atualização das informações. Esse código faz parte da minha classe SQLiteDatabase onde é armazenado internamente as informações referente ao medicamento em questão:

```
void medicamentoUpdate(String TABLE,String medicamento,String tipo,String status,String dosagem,String estoque,
                              String uso,String dataInicial,String dataFinal,String horaInicial,String intervalo){

    SQLiteDatabase db   =   this.getWritableDatabase();

    String where  =  COLUNA_NOME_MEDICAMENTO + " = '" + medicamento + "'";

    ContentValues contentValues     =   new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_TIPO_MEDICAMENTO,tipo);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_STATUS_MEDICAMENTO,status);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_DOSAGEM_MEDICAMENTO,dosagem);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_ESTOQUE_MEDICAMENTO,estoque);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_USO_MEDICAMENTO,uso);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_DATAINICIO_MEDICAMENTO,dataInicial);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_DATAFINAL_MEDICAMENTO,dataFinal);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_HORAINICIAL_MEDICAMENTO,horaInicial);
    contentValues.put(COLUNA_HORAINTERVALO_MEDICAMENTO,intervalo);

    db.update(TABLE,contentValues,where,null);
    db.close();
}
```

*O parâmetro da função acima "String TABLE" é o nome do usuário no qual o medicamento está relacionado. Isso porque, meu aplicativo permite o cadastro de vários usuários e vários medicamentos. Sendo que o cadastro de um novo medicamento, sempre estará relacionado a um usuário.

Se alguém puder me ajudar haverá uma generosa recompensa no futuro, assim que app estiver gerando renda. (Obrigado a todos os interessados e peço que este trecho não seja apagado. Isso porque eu cumpro sempre com a minha palavra)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi responder a minha própria pergunta pois este um dia pode ajudar alguém com a mesma dúvida.

Basicamente o que eu estava tentando fazer é ter acesso ao Banco de dados (SQLite BD). Mas para isso, eu precisava saber o nome da tabela no qual e o nome de medicamento para atualizar as informações.

O que eu descobri é que eu posso passar parâmetros para minha classe Work através do método setInputData(). Ficando assim:

```
// É necessário armazenar o nome da tabela e o nome do remédio (Informações essas para localizar a tabela) numa variável do tipo "Data"

    Data data = new Data.Builder();

    data.putString("TABELA", "nome da tabela");
    data.putString("REMEDIO", "nome do remédio");

    workmanager.setInputData(data.build());

 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(workmanager.build())
```

E depois recuperar as informações na classe Work assim:

```
String TABELA =  inputData.getString("TABELA");
String REMEDIO =  inputData.getString("REMEDIO");
```

Dessa forma, eu obtenho as informações para manipular meu banco de dados e atualizar o que for necessário lá.